# Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I am creating a website using Ruby on Rails 3. I have been working on this project for 2 months and everything was working fine. Suddenly I get the following error after I added the gem 'ckeditor', '3.4.2.pre' to my gemfile. I followed  the ckeditor tutorial here: http://hafizbadrie.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/rails-3-and-ckeditor/  and everything worked fine but since then  whenever I run any command like rails server or bundle install on my console I get the following error:

---

```
WARNING:  Invalid .gemspec format in '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/arel-0.3.3.gemspec'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

I searched on Google and got a solution saying run gem install bundler but that did not solve my error. Because of this error I am not able to proceed further since not a single command is running.

How can i solve this error?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using ree version 1.8.7, couple of gems does not support ree 1.8.7. Check the version of the gem which supports ree 1.8.7 and install the corresponding version of gem. In case you couldn't find the solution, drop a comment